# Assigning User Selected Color to Variable

Tags: excel, vba, colors

Excel VBA n00b here; sorry if I am asking a simple question…

I have created an Excel workbook with a “Settings” sheet that has some data validation (list) cells where the user of the macro can select some options before using the command button to run the macro. One of these cells is a drop down where the user selects a color from a list “Black”, “White”, “Red”, Etc. I have set conditional formatting rules for the cell so that the cell is formatted (filled) corresponding to the color that the user has picked. However, when I try to read this cell using the Interior.Color option, it seems as though the conditional formatting hasn’t truly “filled” the background color of the cell in a way that can be read by my VBA macro.

I have tried instead to figure out how to convert a string into a constant; because then I could simply add “vb” in front of the cell’s text value for colors like “Black” and use the constant to assign the color to a variable. However, I am unable to find an efficient way to evaluate a string into a VBA constant.

*TL;DR*
**What is the best way to allow the user to select and preview a color before running a macro, and then having that macro read the user’s selection and assign it to a variable?**

Comment: Conditional format = `.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your questions, but maybe this gives an idea?

> However, I am unable to find an efficient way to evaluate a string
> into a VBA constant.

use formulas to evaluate the string to certain numbers, and then use those numbers to create you variables.

Set up a table (not an excel table) with values in two columns, column A includes the different string options and column b includes the pre determined valuation.

Then use a vlookup or preferably index match to evaluate the string.